# In Python how do I slice a list based on an item in the list?

Tags: python, list, slice

```
list1 = ['5', '3', '2', '1']
j = '3'
```

How do I extract from that list from j to the end of the list? In this example giving me:

```
['3', '2', '1']
```

when I know j, j is always in the list and the list is always filled with unique values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so since you know the value of j here, we can get the index of j in the list using `list1.index(j)`
now we have to get all the items after j, so we can use this: `list1[list1.index(j):]`

what this basically does is, it gives all the values from the specified index (our case j) till the end of the list
this should give you the desired output!

Answer (score 0):

As comments suggest you can get the index number of an item in a `list` by using `index` method. Just like this:

```py
>>> list1 = ['5', '3', '2', '1']
>>> list1.index('5')
0
>>> list1.index('1')
3
```

And then use it to reach the item you want:

```py
>>> i  = list1.index('2')
>>> list1[i]
'2'
```